# How can I limit size of logfile in Redis?

Tags: logging, redis, stackexchange.redis

I use Redis in project. And It seems,  that logfiles grws unlimited.

Does somebody knows, how I can set max size of logfile in Redis?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use logrotate?

Comment: Yes, this is way to fix my problem, but I thought, there is some configuration in redis. Can I use logrotate without root?

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar kind of issue, i.e. My logfile is Redis is continuously increasing in size. I want to archive/delete the log file after reaching to some fixed number. Does anyone know how to do the same?